# get the name of the argument that was sent

Tags: python, enums

I need a way to get the parameter that was sent name.
for example

```
class Message:  
    I = 1
    LIKE = 2
    COODING = 3

sendData(Message.LIKE)


def sendData(arg):
    print(arg.name) -> Message.LIKE
    print(arg.value) -> 2
```

And before some says use class Message(Enum):  this is prebuilt Class so I can't change the class itself.

I have tried stuff like

```
sendData(enum(Message.LIKE))
```

and check via inspect module the method call signature with no luck

EDIT:
This is no duplicated, as I says. I cant change class Message to class Message(Enum)

Comment: If you want strings, why not just use those as the values, rather than numbers?

Comment: cus i need the number and the string

Comment: `Message.LIKE` is not a name; it's an expression used to generate a value of type `int`. The value `2` bound to `arg` knows nothing about how it was provided to `sendData`.

Comment: (For all `sendData` knows, `Message` wasn't even involved: it could have been called like `sendData(2)`.)

Comment: I already know this.
I'm looking for way to make Message.LIKE to Enum single instance